# Getting value from rows in admin list view

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have an admin list view.

The mysql table for that view has 4 columns/fields: `id`, `name`, `email`, `phone`

To that admin list view, I have added a button. A user can select one/multiple records in that list view, and then the user can click that button.

When the button is clicked, I want to echo/print email-field-value(s) of those selected record(s).

I have created this function inside the controller file of that admin list view:

```
public function emailVolunteerApproval() {
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $pks = $input->post->get('cid', array(), 'array');
    print_r($pks);
}
```

This function prints the IDs of the selected records, but I don't know how to proceed from here so that I could get the email-field-values of those respective records.

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour].

Comment: You should get data from the model.